# Proof -sine(sum) <= sum of sines

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have no idea how to prove it. Could you help me?
  $$x_i\in[0, \pi]$$$$i=1,...,n$$
$$|\sin{\Sigma_{i=1}^nx_i}|\le\Sigma_{i=1}^n\sin{x_i}$$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove it using induction.

for $n=1$ it is true.

Lemma:
$$
|\sin (x+y)| = |\sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos x|
\le |\sin x ||\cos y| + |\sin y ||\cos x|
\le |\sin x | + |\sin y | $$

if it is true for $n$:
$$
\left|\sin \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i\right|
= \left|\sin \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + x_{n+1}\right] \right|
 \le \left|\sin \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right| + \sin x_{n+1}
$$
using the lemma, plus the fact that $x_{n+1}\in [0,\pi]$

$$
\left|\sin \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i\right|
\le \sum_{i=1}^n \sin x_i +\sin x_{n+1}
$$using the hypothesis.

---

note that there is also another result stating that
$$
0\le a_i \le 1, 0\le x_i\le \pi \implies 
\sin\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i
\right)
\ge 
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sin\left( x_i
\right)
$$